# Json String with comment out quotes in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, json

I have a JSON string hardcoded in my Javascript.

```
valiJsonString = '{"ssss","ddddddddd\"ddd"}';
```

The DOM says -> `{"ssss","ddddddddd"ddd"}`

Can someone tell me why javascript replace my `\"` into `"` ?

```
// try to parse
valiJsonString secureEvalJSON (valiJsonString)   //<-- error: jsonString is not valid
```

[**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4wVaR/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The DOM says" doesn't make much sense, as the DOM doesn't say anything. Do you mean the object browser in Firebug (or some other development console)?

Now, inside a string, `\"` is the quote character. You have to compensate for this escaping since you do not want it, but instead a verbatim slash.

So perhaps you want `\\` followed by `"`, which is the slashed character followed by the quote character.

In addition, the given JSON looks like it ought to represent an *array* not an *object*, since you have no keys:

```
var str = '["ssss","ddddddddd\\"ddd"]';
```

The actual value of this JSON-format string inside your browser is now:

```
["ssss","ddddddddd\"ddd"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`\` is an escape character. try `\\`

Answer (score 2):

If you want your string to come through escaped, then you need to escape your escape character:

```
valiJsonString = '{"ssss","ddddddddd\\"ddd"}';
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added second \ (\ is escape char) and fixed lack of = and type of table {} vs []

http://jsfiddle.net/4wVaR/9/